# Linker can't place a block into free memory range

Tags: c, linker, iar

I use microcontroller CC3220S with 256KB of RAM memory and have some issue with memory placement.

IAR ELF Linker V7.80.1.28/LNX for ARM

Copyright 2007-2016 IAR Systems AB.

Error[Lp011]: section placement failed
            unable to place Block P3-P4-1 (min size 0x795, align 0x8) in: <[0x2003e6d4-0x2003f7ef]>

Calculated free space in range <[0x2003e6d4-0x2003f7ef]> is equal to 0x111B, which definitely bigger than Block P3-P4-1 min size 0x795. So even despite the fact that overall memory utilization is around 99% (259963 of 262144) but it still enough free space to allocate additional block P3-P4-1.

I didn't managed to find any particular info in TI and IAR documents, so I would be very grateful if anyone can help with clarifying details or pointing me to the resource about following questions:

What could be a root cause of issue with placing P3-P4-1 even if memory seems to be enough?

@nivpeled Unfortunately I cannot share the whole file, but here is a part of it

```
"P3-P4", part 1 of 3:                      0x2bf40
  .text               ro code  0x20004040   0x2ef4  ds_network.o
  .rodata             const    0x2002e6b0    0x4cc  d_network.o
  Initializer bytes   const    0x2002eb7c    0x39f  <for P3-P4-1> (used: 0x38b)
                             - 0x2002ff80  0x2bf40
"P3-P4", part 2 of 3:                       0xe85c
  .bss                zero     0x2002ff80   0x6d78  heap_4.o
  .bss                zero     0x2003e7d9      0x1  interrupt_event.o
                                     0x2003e7da   0xe85a
"A0":                                        0x800
  CSTACK                       0x2003f7f0    0x800  <Block>
    .stack            uninit   0x2003f7f0    0x800  startup_cc32xx_iar.o
                             - 0x2003fff0    0x800
"P3-P4", part 3 of 3 (*** FAILED ***):       0x795
  P3-P4-1                                    0x795  <Init block>
    .data             inited                  0x78  diagnostic.o
    .data             inited                   0x1  d_als.o 
                                             0x795
```

B.R. Alex.

Comment: Your free space in total memory is smaller than 0x111B range. That doesn't add up. Perhaps there is already something else placed on that range.

Comment: Thanks for comment. I have already checked map file for overlapping with another blocks, but no obvious placement into mention range is present.

Comment: Why is there `interrupt_event.o` (0x2003e7d9) right in the middle of your 0x2003e6d4-0x2003f7ef range? I am not familiar with CC3220S, but this placement looks very disjoined. There are big gaps everywhere, breaking the free space. I don't think we can solve this without knowing the placement declarations (in linker script and source files).

Answer (score 1):

A map file can be generated by passing the `--map MyMapFile.txt` string to ilinkarm.
Generate the map file and check if you have a **continuous** free block of memory of size >= 0x795 in the correct memory range.

Comment: Thanks for comment. I have already done that, but no obvious placement into mention range is present.

Comment: can you please share your map file?

Comment: I cannot share the whole file.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all for responsiveness. 
I solved my issue with forcing linker to place big aligned blocks which helps to organize free memory and avoid such a curious problems.